# How to get a list of twitter accounts associated with blockchain addresses?

Tags: ether, wallets, nft

Twitter users can associate and verify a blockchain account and NFT with their account and set them as profile pictures, yet the Twitter API has no way to access this information.

Is there any way to get all of the twitter accounts that have associated with a blockchain address and those addresses?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If the Twitter API does not provide a call for the particular function you want then it's usually because Twitter doesn't want you interacting with that data. Circumventing rates/access to resources doesn't usually work, you get rate limited, the resource you need is access controlled or you throw up all sorts of red flags on their infrastructure which brings heat on you.

It sounds like what your after is a basic profile scraper - you would be better off doing this through some kind of web automation. Selenium + Python is a good start.

I can see that the Contract Address (i.e the NFT owner) has a class of:

```
<span class="css-901oao css-16my406 r-poiln3 r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0">Contract Address</span>
```

Start by installing Python and work with the Selenium Browser driver to automate your process. You will likely need to use a login to avoid using the API to avoid having your Python script run into 403s as Twitter doesn't like users not being logged in, but building your script with UI automation will help you bypass any API limitations and probably allow you to do a lot more.